# Using PowerShell class to invoke a "[namespace.class]::method" style command

Tags: .net, powershell

I created a powershell object via .net to invoke commands.
When I invoke normal commands like 'Get-Process' I had no problems:

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process").AddParameter(...).Invoke()
```

but I'm not able to invoke a .net method with the syntax "[namespace.class]::method", just to make an example to invoke [System.IO.File]::Exists("c:\boo.txt").

I tried with

```
ps.AddCommand("[System.IO.File]::Exists(\"c:\\boo.txt\")").Invoke()

ps.AddCommand("[System.IO.File]::Exists").AddArgument("c:\\boo.txt").Invoke()
```

and some others.
It always throws an exception which says that the command specified is not recognized.

There is a way to invoke that type of command?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `script` to the pipeline since calling out to .NET requires script i.e. .NET methods are not considered PowerShell `commands` e.g.:

```
static void Main()
{
     PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
     ps.AddScript(@"[IO.File]::Exists('C:\Users\Keith\foo.txt')");
     foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
     {
         Console.WriteLine(result);
     }
}
```